# Meteor, Iron Router and collection state in the client/server

Tags: meteor, iron-router

This is my code:

```
Router.route "/", ->
  users = Meteor.users.find().fetch().length
  if users > 0
    @render 'header'
  else
    @render 'register'
```

And the problem is simple: the route is called 2 time, first in the `find()` and later in the `find.fetch()`.

I only want to know the number of user to determinate what template render, but in the client side is necessary fetch first, and in the server I can do it, but I don't know how to say that render the template from the client....

I need something like callback after find to know the result and do an action. How do it? Only determinate the length and take a decision, it's simple!

Answer (score 0):

The reason your route is being called twice is that there is some latency before the data from your server arrives client, so when you first call it,

```
Meteor.users.find().fetch()
```

is just an empty array. Only after a fraction of second it becomes populated with some data. In general there is little you can do about, but in your particular case - since you only need to know if a user is logged in or not - you can use `Meteor.userId()` function instead.

If by some reason, you prefer to have the collection data being fetched prior to your route's action, then you should probably use `waitOn` hook with a custom subscription which is responsible for fetching the set of data you're interested in.